# java: write to xml file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

in java I need to create xml file which look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NikuDataBus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd">
    <Header action="write" externalSource="NIKU" objectType="customObjectInstance" version="8.1.0.4247"/>
    <customObjectInstances objectCode="hen_allockey_p">
        <instance instanceCode="MIG5033028" objectCode="hen_allockey_p"
        parentInstanceCode="001260" parentObjectCode="project">
            <CustomInformation>
                <ColumnValue name="hen_from">200801</ColumnValue>
                <ColumnValue name="name">MIG5033028</ColumnValue>
                <ColumnValue name="code">MIG5033028</ColumnValue>
            <OBSAssocs/>
            <Security/>
        </instance>
    </customObjectInstances>
</NikuDataBus>
```

I found something on google, but it didn't match to my needs. And as I am new with java, I don't know how to adapt it to my needs.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what are your needs and how the tutorials you found didn't match your needs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [read excel, write to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174454/read-excel-write-to-xml)

Comment: @jasso...I thik that my need is to get source code which generate xml file I did mention above :)...becasue I am working on it like 6 days...I have never work with java and I don't know why my boss gave my to do this...and this is just a fraction of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it like this. It is bad looking code, but it works for me, maybe there are some errors caused by copy and paste

```
public class POIExcelReader {

private void setHenAllocKeyHeader(StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.append ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n"
            + "<NikuDataBus xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd\">\r\n"
            + "<Header action=\"write\" externalSource=\"NIKU\"objectType=\"customObjectInstance\" version=\"8.1.0.4247\"/>\r\n"
            + "<customObjectInstances objectCode=\"hen_allockey_p\">\r\n"
            + "<instance instanceCode=\"MIG5033028\" objectCode=\"hen_allockey_p\" parentInstanceCode=\"001260\" parentObjectCode=\"project\">\r\n");
}

private void setHenAllocKeyBottom (StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.append ("<OBSAssocs/>\r\n"
            +"<Security/>\r\n"
            +"</customObjectInstances>\r\n" 
            + "</NikuDataBus>\r\n");
}

protected void jobRun() throws Exception {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    setHenAllocKeyHeader(sb);
    String prolog = sb.toString();

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    setHenAllocKeyBottom(sb);
    String epilog = sb.toString();


    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test\\osem.xml");
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    osw.write(prolog);
    osw.write(epilog);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();

}
public static void main(String[] args){
try{
            job.jobRun();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use JAXB instead. Create classes NikuDataBus, Header, CustomInformation etc. Mark them as @XmlEntity. Create and populate objects.

```
NikyDataBus dataBus = new NikuDataBus();
dataBus.setHeader(....)
//etc, etc....

File f = new File("mydata.xml");
Marshaller m = JAXBContext.newInstance(NikuDataBus.class, Header.class, CustomInformation.class ).createMarshaller().marshal(dataBus, f)
```

Comment: it looks nice...but JAVA realy isn't my language...could you please be more specific with code...I will realy appreciate your help...I am strugglig long time on this...thanks

Comment: @skaryu - Since you have an XML schema, you might find it easiest to generate your JAXB model from a schema and use that to do your marshalling/unmarshalling.  The following is an example of how to do this:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago and the website i used that gave me a good understanding of differnt ways to code it is.

[This website](http://www.javazoom.net/services/newsletter/xmlgeneration.html)  provides you many different ways to code the xml: String, DOM, SAX

```
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
        //create string from xml tree
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        trans.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();

        //Writing the string to a file
        OutputStream outputStream;
        byte buf[] = xmlString.getBytes();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        for (byte element : buf) {
            outputStream.write(element);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        buf = null;
```

Comment: thanks...but I've already seen that page....and also many more...but I still don't uderstand how to write the script which create this xml file

Comment: are you talking bout writting it to a file?? liek you already have the XML and you want to write to file?

Comment: I need create file and then write it there

Comment: Well the website above teaches you how to create the XML, and to write it: ill edit

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experiences with [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). You just make the objects and populate them with whatever data you want, and finally you just `xstream.toXML(object);` to get the string of the xml.

Comment: If the site is down, like I seem to be experiencing, you could already learn some things from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XStream). +1 for adding XStream to my 'library'. Wim

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your XML is based on an XML Schema (`../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd`). If this is the case you can use [XML Beans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). Given the XML Schema, XML Beans will produce a set of Java classes (or a jar file) that you can use to create your XML progtrammatically.

The advantage is that your XML is compliant with your XML Schema. I found this approach useful in the past, and I have good experience with XML Beans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scilca XML Progression package available at GitHub.

```
Node rootNode = Node.constructNode(<NikuDataBusxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xsd/nikuxog_customObjectInstance.xsd">");

rootNode.addChildNode(Node.constructNode("<Header action="write" externalSource="NIKU" objectType="customObjectInstance" version="8.1.0.4247"/>"));

String customObj = "<customObjectInstances objectCode="hen_allockey_p">" 
                        + "<instance instanceCode="MIG5033028" objectCode="hen_allockey_p" parentInstanceCode="001260" parentObjectCode="project">" 
                        + "<CustomInformation>"
                              + "<ColumnValue name="hen_from">200801</ColumnValue>"
                              + "<ColumnValue name="name">MIG5033028</ColumnValue>"
                              + "<ColumnValue name="code">MIG5033028</ColumnValue>"
                        + "</CustomInformation>"
                        + "<OBSAssocs/><Security/>"
                        + "</instance>"
                        + "</customObjectInstances>"

  // Now build to customObject element using a VirtualXML Iterator

 XMLIterator xi = new VirtualXML.XMLIterator(customObj);
 Node customO = Node.readFromFile(xi);

 rootNode.addChildNode(customO);

 Document XmlDocument = new Document(rootNode);
 XmlDocument.addXmlDeclaration(1.0, "UTF-8", null);

 XMLWriter xw = XmlDocument.getWriter();
 xw.write("D:/file.txt");
```