# Java / Groovy&Grails File write

Tags: java, grails, groovy, java-io

I have tried different ways to write a string to a file.

```
File file = new File(eventPath)
file.withWriterAppend { it << xmlDocument }
```

OR

```
file << xmlDocument
```

In this way, the string when the file size reaches 1kb is interrupted.

If I do this way (as explained here: [java: write to xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177601/java-write-to-xml-file))

```
File file = new File("foo")
if (file.exists()) {
    assert file.delete()
    assert file.createNewFile()
}

boolean append = true
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, append)
BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)

100.times { buffWriter.write "foo" }

buffWriter.flush()
buffWriter.close()
```

Happens that the string gets repeated. 
How can I use the first method without have limit on string size? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does:

```
new File(eventPath).withWriterAppend { it.writeLine xmlDocument }
```

work?

Comment: no I get always error in writing the string. ex: string = <event><title></title></event>, the result in the file is like: <event><title></title><event><event><titl.

Comment: @Pietro Odd...  Not doing any sort of redirection into the file as well are you?  Can you give a brief runnable example which exhibits the double writing you seem to be getting?

Comment: Thanks you made me think. The problem was when I zip the xml files. The buffer was 1024.